# Google desktop not indexing new emails

Tags: google-desktop-search

About a month ago, Google Desktop stopped indexing my outlook emails. The service is still running. I run an update with the Google updater. But there is no change. Any search I run will only return emails going back from about a month ago.

What should I do to get it indexing again?

Comment: What version are you using (both outlook & google desktop) ?

Comment: The Google desktop service is "Google Desktop Manager 5.8.811.4345"
I'm using Outlook 2007

Comment: I get this too. I assumed Google Desktop simply filled up the amount of emails/files it can index and I switched to Xobni to email searching instead.

Comment: Google says to rebuild your index from scratch: http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13837

Some people have solved it by deleting some malformed emails that might have tripped up the indexer: http://groups.google.com/group/google-desktop_something-broken/msg/61be7a85fd5e01e9

Comment: You know [Google Desktop is discontinued](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/09/google-desktop-will-be-discontinued.html)? Maybe you should check if windows search (available in microsoft update) fits your needings, too - you will get more troubles with Google Desktop over time.

Answer (score 1):

Istead of google desktop I suggest that you can use Outlook 2007 Instant Search which has email indexing.

> http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/find-a-message-or-item-by-using-instant-search-HA001230585.aspx

Also Google Desktop is **discontinued** so you cant download it from google and its no longer supported nor updated. You can only grab old version from 3rd party webistes.

Answer (score 0):

Following-up @[Miss Cellanie](https://superuser.com/users/18662/miss-cellanie)'s comments, the [rebuild index](http://desktop.Google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13837) process is one I have had to use before.

---

If Google Desktop is no longer indexing new content or files past a certain date, make sure that indexing's still enabled. Here's how:

1. Click the Desktop icon in your system tray.
2. Select Options.
3. Click the Desktop Search tab. If you're using an older version of Google Desktop, click Local Indexing.
4. Select the 'Enable content indexing for new items' checkbox. For older versions of Google Desktop, deselect the checkbox next to 'Disable Indexing.'
5. Make sure all relevant file types are selected in the 'Search Types' section.
6. Click the Save Preferences button.

If you've correctly set your preferences and the problem persists, you may need to re-build your Google Desktop index from scratch to resolve the issue. Here's how:

1. Uninstall Google Desktop and completely erase your old index.
2. Click the Start menu on the computer taskbar.
3. Select Programs.
4. Select Google Desktop.
5. Select Uninstall Google Desktop.
6. Select the 'Remove completely for all users' option.
7. Click the Yes button in the confirmation window.
8. Deselect the 'Keep indexes in case I want to install Google Desktop again later' option.
9. Click the Uninstall button.

   > Make sure to uncheck 'Keep indexes in case I want to install Google Desktop again later' when uninstalling to completely erase your old index.
10. Restart your computer.
11. Reinstall the latest version of Desktop from http://desktop.google.com. After reinstalling, Desktop should correctly index your computer's content.

Answer (score 0):

goto Options -> Select the "Desktop Search" tab, Uncheck the box next to "Enable content indexing for new items."...it worked like a charm to me