# google desktop search (GDS) fails

Tags: google-desktop-search

Google desktop search seems easily fail on my PC after some time. It stops indexing new files(executable, shortcut) and not in indexing status either. I tried to reinstall several times. Does anyone know how to resolve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment on [another GDS question](https://superuser.com/questions/45209/google-desktop-not-indexing-new-emails) indicates that you might need to rebuild the GDS index from scratch.  From the [official support page](http://desktop.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13837):

**Fix #1:** Make sure indexing is still enabled.

1. Click the Desktop icon in your system tray.
2. Select *Options*.
3. Click the *Desktop Search* tab.  If using an older version of GDS, click *Local Indexing*.
4. Select the *'Enable content indexing for new items'* checkbox.  For older versions, **deselect** the *'Disable Indexing'* checkbox.
5. Make sure all relevant file types are selected in the *'Search Types'* section.
6. Click *Save Preferences*.

**Fix #2:** If Fix #1 doesn't work, rebuild your GDS index from scratch.

1. Uninstall GDS and completely erase your old index.

   1. In Start menu > Programs > Google Desktop, select **Uninstall Google Desktop**.
   2. Select *'Remove completely for all users'*.
   3. Click *Yes* in the confirmation dialog.
   4. **Deselect** *'Keep indexes in case I want to install Google Desktop again later'*.
   5. Click *Uninstall*.
2. Restart your computer.
3. Reinstall the latest version of Google Desktop.  After reinstalling, GDS should correctly index your system.